If there are $n-1$ vectors with dimension $n$ with sums of components in each $=0$. Prove the abs(det) form from those vectors are the same.
I think the title is a bit confusing so I'll explain more.
Suppose there is a vector $(a_1\phantom{2}a_2\phantom{2}...\phantom{2}a_n)$ where $(\sum^n_{i=1} a_i = 0)$. Now suppose there is a matrix with n-1 column vectors with the same condition, the last column is a column of zero. Prove the absolute value of minors of entry $a_{in}$ (i = {1,2,...,n}) are all equal.
For example: given the following matrix.
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \cr c & d & 0 \cr -a-c & -b-d & 0 \end{pmatrix}
The absolute values of minors of entry $a_{13},\phantom{2}a_{23} \phantom{2} and \phantom{2} a_{33}$ are all $\lvert{ad-bc}\lvert$
Thank you for your time and please consider taking some time to answer my question.
P.S Please tell me how to improve my question, it's not a troll post and I've tested 15 matrices using RNG and the results are consistent (all the minors have the same value). Thank you everyone who helped improving my post.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Isn't the value for the minor $a_{23}$ positive? $2.635\cdot 0.14-(-2.11\cdot 1.96)=4.5045$?

@DietrichBurde, the actual output of the script has 16 significant figures, including the entries in matrix. For the sake of brevity, I'll round those numbers up to 3 significant figures and the differences of each minors are less than $10^{−14}$ so they are assumed to be equal. Also I made a terrible mistake of forgetting to specify that I'm talking about absolute value. Sorry for not including this in the post earlier. Please help me now that this is clarified.

For mathematics, you should give the entries just variable names, so $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \cr c & d & 0 \cr -a-c & -b-d & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ So no need to discuss any numerical values. So the minor $a_{33}$ is just $ad-bc$. The other two are $-(ad-bc)$ and again $ad-bc$. So we are done.

@DietrichBurde Thank you for your advice, this helps improving the clarity a lot!

Suppose we modify the matrix by setting $a_{ni}=1$ and $a_{nj}=-1$. In the example, with $i=1$ and $j=3$, it would look like this:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}2.64&-2.11&1\\-4.59&1.97&0\\1.96&0.14&-1\end{array}\right]
$$
The determinant of this matrix is still $0$, because every column sum is $0$, which is a nontrivial linear relation between the rows. (The first $n-1$ columns sum to $0$ by assumption; the last column sums to $0$ because $1-1 = 0$.)
We can also compute the determinant differently: by an expansion along the last column. Most terms of this expansion will be $0$, but the $1$ and $-1$ we've added will be multiplied by their respective minors (up to some alternating sign factors). So the sum or difference of those minors should give us the determinant of $0$, which means that the two minors are equal, in absolute value.
Since $i$ and $j$ are arbitrary, this is true for any two of the minors.

Misha Lavrov's answer is very elegant. I was working on the details of the following argument when that came. In the end I decided to post this anyway.
Let those vectors be $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\in V\subseteq\Bbb{R}^n$, where
$$V=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\mid \sum_{i=1}^na_i=0\}$$ is the zero-sum subspace.
If they are linearly dependent, then all the minors in question are equal to zero. If they are linearly independent, then they span the space $V$. As ${\bf1}:=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ spans the orthogonal complement $V^\perp$, it follows that any vector $v$ can be written as a sum
$$v=v_V+ \lambda {\bf 1},$$
where $v_V\in V$, and the constant $\lambda$ can be calculated as the inner product $\lambda=\dfrac1n\,v\cdot{\bf1}\in\Bbb{R}$.
By the basic properties of determinants
$$
\det(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1},v)=\det(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1},\lambda{\bf1})
=\lambda\det(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1},{\bf1}).
$$
In particular, if we use a vector of indeterminates, $v_n=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, then the inner product equals $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)$. Consequently
$$
\det(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-1},v_n)=Ax_1+Ax_2+\cdots Ax_n,\qquad(*)$$
where
$A=\det(v_1,v_2,\ldots,{\bf 1})/n.$
Comparing the formula $(*)$ with what you get from expanding $\det(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ w.r.t. the last column gives the claim.
